# Making record available only to certain models in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a weird design question.  I have a model called Article, which has a bunch of attributes.  I also have an article search which does something like this:

```
Article.project_active.pending.search(params)
```

where search builds a query based on certain params.  I'd like to be able to limit results based on a user, that is, to have some articles have only a subset of users which can see them.
For instance, I have an article A that I assign to writers 1,2,3,4.  I want them to be able to see A, but if User 5 searches, I don't want that user to see.  Also, I'd like to be able to assign some articles to ALL users.

Not sure if that was clear, but I'm looking for the best way to do this.  Should I just store a serialized array with a list of user_id's and have -1 in there if it's available to All?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a join table between Users and Articles called view_permissions to indicate that a user has permission to view a specific article.

```
class ViewPermission
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :view_permissions
end

class Article
  has_many :view_permissions
end
```

For example, if you wanted User 1 to be able to view Article 3 you would do the following:

```
ViewPermission.create(:user_id => 1, :article_id => 3)
```

You could then scope your articles based on the view permissions and a user:

```
class Article
  scope :viewable_by, lambda{ |user| joins(:view_permissions).where('view_permissions.user_id = ?', user.id) }
end
```

To search for articles viewable by a specific user, say with id 1, you could do this:

```
Article.viewable_by(User.find(1)).project_active.pending.search(params)
```

Finally, if you want to assign an article to all users, you should add an viewable_by_all boolean attribute to articles table that when set to true allows an article to be viewable by all users. Then modify your scope to take that into account:

```
class Article
  scope :viewable_by, lambda{ |user|
    joins('LEFT JOIN view_permissions on view_permissions.article_id = articles.id')
    .where('articles.viewable_by_all = true OR view_permissions.user_id = ?', user.id)
    .group('articles.id')
  }
end
```

Comment: Hi Pan-  Same question to you.  Do we create one record for every writer if we want this article viewable by all?  Doesn't seem super efficient.

Comment: Made one quick update to the scope so that it uses a LEFT JOIN so that if no view_permissions exist the query still works.

Comment: This is great. The only problem is in Postgresql I get these funky group by errors which want me to include every field in articles. Is there a way to avoid this grouping error?

Comment: You should be able to group by articles.* as well: .group('articles.*') that way you can include all the article columns in your select statement. You can also use an EXISTS query if this doesn't work.

Comment: No luck with articles.*.  What would the EXISTS query look like?

Comment: Well just added this method instead, which seems to work fine  def self.attributes_for_sql
    str = ''
    Article.new.attributes.keys.each {|a| str << ' articles.'+a+','}
    str
  end

Comment: the exists would be in the where clause ('OR EXISTS ( SELECT vp.id FROM view_permissions vp WHERE vp.user_id = ? AND vp.article_id = articles.id )', user.id) then you wouldn't have to do any grouping.

Comment: Sorry to revive this question pan, but why are we using the group_by clause at all?

Comment: Because an article has_many view_permissions and if you join to view permissions you have the chance of getting more than one result per article. Since the scope is on article you don't want that, because there's a chance that you'll use this scope and end up with duplicate articles in your view. If you feel confident that the query will only return one view permission then you can remove the group clause. That part is up to you, but it's a good practice to limit the results this way if there is a chance of multiple records.

Comment: The group clause also communicates that in a join you want to eliminate more than one result per article. It's a good idea to communicate this incase the view permissions change at some point in the future too. For instance if the view permissions simply become permissions and include read and write access, in which case it would be easy to get multiple results per article.

Answer (score 2):

If an Article can be assigned to multiple Writers and a Writer can be assigned to multiple Articles, I would create an Assignment model:

```
class Assignment < AR::Base
  belongs_to :writer
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Then you can use has_many :through:

```
class Article < AR::Base
   has_many :assignments
   has_many :writers, :through => :assignments
end

class Writer < AR::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :articles, :through => :assignments
end
```

Comment: Jordan-  Thanks for the answer.  The problem occurs when you want to assign an article to all writers.  Seems like a lot of records for just one article no?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just has [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) instead of having the Assignment model?

Comment: @dave not sure how many writers you have, but it's usually not a big deal. @andrew I always go straight to has_many :through; because, I always end up adding a column or two. For this, I could see :created_at being useful.